# jQuery UI same classes for different styles (css)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a now a few things implemented in my website which, for example a few jQuery UI buttons or the datepicker. But now I have the problem that my datepicker needs a class which my buttons also use. But I have to edit this css-class for my new datepicker. But if i do that, it will destroy the style of the button.

How can I solve this problem? With `<style>...</style>` in the header of each HTMl file?

Comment: You can set more than one CSS class with space separation, like: `class="class1 class2"`, is that what you want?

Comment: There is only one difference between the css of the button and the datepicker, for example `background:`. I don't know whether it is that useful to create a new class with another name.

Comment: Then you can use `button.class-name` instead to create a new one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try directly referncing the date picker here iv done the header of the datepicker

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header{
    background: none;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Hope this helps